# ng-bind-html and angular.js error

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html

I´m playing with angular.js and try to learn ng-bind and ng-bind-html.

First, my code:

```
<div ng-app="module" ng-controller="controller as ctrl">
<div ng-bind-html="ctrl.html"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

<script>
var themodule = angular.module("module", ["ngSanitize"]);
themodule.controller("controller", [function()
{
this.html = "<strong>Hello</strong><div>More</div>";
}
]);
</script>
```

Even when it works, in the console appears the following ERROR:

```
Error: c.push is not a function
yc/this.$get</D.$$addBindingInfo<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:73:319
$d</<.compile/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:214:329
$@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:70:197
B@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:59:255
g@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:51:335
B@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:59:199
g@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:51:335
D/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:50:444
uc/d/</<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:18:4
Pe/this.$get</n.prototype.$eval@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:126:11
Pe/this.$get</n.prototype.$apply@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:126:236
uc/d/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:17:477
e@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:36:313
uc/d@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:17:1
uc@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:18:179
Jd@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:17:1
@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:250:429
a@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:164:283
lf/c@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:32:384
 <div class="ng-binding" ng-bind-html="ctrl.html">
```

I searched but I could not find anything about it.

**Does anyone know WHY and HOW to resolve it?**

Thanks!

Comment: Try use the right version of ng-sanitize i.e `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-sanitize.js"`. Your angular core version and sanitize versions do not match

Comment: @PSL Thanks a lot! BIG lesson learned!

Answer (score 2):

try to use  this version of angular-sanitize.js

```
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-sanitize.js"
```

OR

```
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-sanitize.js"
```

and use

```
var app = angular.module("myFirstApp", ['ngSanitize']);/*"angular-sanitize.js",
which has functions for removing potentially dangerous tokens from the HTML.*/
```

I hope your problem will be resolved.

Comment: what do you want to say?

Comment: format your contents, its easy to write contents. But make it attractive, it plays crucial role in stack.